# example of how to separate sample project into separate files?

Tags: flutter, directory-structure

When you create a new project in Flutter v3.19, it creates a default app in `/lib/main.dart`

`/lib/main.dart` contains three classes:

`class MyApp extends StatelessWidget`

`class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget`

`class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>`

What is the best way to organize the file structure of the project so that those classes can be in separate folders/files? This will be for a small project.

Is there an example of what `main.dart` should look like so that it can import those classes? I couldn't find an example in the Flutter docs about this.

I tried to find an example of this, but couldn't. I would expect either simple docs from Flutter that explain this or the sample project to be setup with this in mind.

I found examples of folder structure, but nothing specifically for the sample project that comes with Flutter.

Comment: If you go to https://docs.flutter.dev/, you can see the [Samples](https://flutter.github.io/samples/#) button where you can access a lot of project samples including their source codes.

Comment: Thank you @DhafinRayhan. I found an example which matches pretty closely what I'm looking for:
https://flutter.github.io/samples/testing_app.html

This shows a simple folder structure and contains related tests. Also includes basic routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple format you can create two simple file cut and paste the code like following

cut
`class MyApp extends StatelessWidget` and create a file my_app.dart and paste it.

cut

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage>
```

together and create a file named home_page.dart and paste it.

now you will find some error on the newly created file add import `'package:flutter/material.dart';` on both files. now you will find an error on **main.dart**  so you have to import **my_app.dart** file and also import **home_page** in my_app Page.

**file Structure**

[image]

**main.dart**

[image]

**my_app.dart**

[image]

**home_page.dart**
[image]

import file path will change according to project name and file structure

Comment: Thank you, @dev.skas. That's very clear and helpful.